# Space Shuttle: What are the filters in the attitude error calculation?

Tags: space-shuttle, simulation, attitude-determination-and-control

Here's a schematic from the space shuttle training manuals showing how the "attitude" error signal used to drive the thrust vector controllers was determined.

"Attitude" in quote marks because it was in fact a mix of attitude error, attitude *rate* error, and normal acceleration error signals.

The errors would be separately gained, then *filtered*, then summed, then *filtered* again then be gained again if the crew flipped a manual switch, then be *filtered* again---before finally at last being sent to the thrust vector controllers.

That's a lot of filtering! And now I'm wondering: what the purpose? To remove high-frequency noise? Or to smooth the error signal again and again and again in case the preceding operation (gaining through nonlinear/discontinuous lookup tables, summing) had made the signal... insufficiently smooth?

And more importantly! What would the filters look like? Would they be low-pass filters (I want to say yes)? Would they have different cutoff frequencies? Is there an algorithm for them that I could look at (since so many space shuttle algorithms are public on the web)?

[image]

Comment: See here for info on the orbiter FCS filters: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19850008594/downloads/19850008594.pdf

Comment: Oh man every answer I get from you is gold. Ha ha. Thank you :)

Comment: @OrganicMarble: any chance you have a reference for the bending filter algorithm itself, or at least a good practical/mathematical description of them?

Comment: No, this is kinda out of my wheelhouse. I just know enough about it to know the answer already posted is wrong.